# How to limit the depth of the directory visited by the Unix command find?

Tags: shell, unix, find, ksh

Similar question has already been asked but I am not satisfyed with the answers. Indeed, I want to use the Unix find command and the find command I use does not allow the option -maxdepth. However, there is an option -depth but I did not succed to use it in a way that I am satisfied. I use ksh shell.

Comment: What have you tried, and what makes the results unsatisfactory?

Comment: Does `-depth` give an error, or return wrong results, or...?

Comment: Does this link help at all: https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/65786-controlling-depth-find.html ?  It seems to suggest that `depth` may not actually do what you're after (implied).

Comment: Also post your system name `uname -sr`

Comment: See [limit POSIX find to specific depth](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/275637/limit-posix-find-to-specific-depth)

Comment: The command: > find . -depth 1 returns: find: 0652-009 There is a missing conjunction. And the command: > uname -sr returns: AIX 1

Comment: The `-depth` option indicates "depth-first search". It doesn't take an argument and won't help you limit how deep find will go into subdirectories.

Comment: As a workaround, you could print the paths you find and pipe it through `awk` using `/` as a separator and only print lines with less than the requisite number of fields since each field would correspond to a level of directories.

Comment: Try this `find /startDir | awk -F'/' '{print NF,":",$0}'` to see what I mean - the number is the depth.

Comment: the problem of this command is the find has to do exactely the same work, it must go through the entire tree before stopping. For instance, depth of the start directory is 100, and I want to stop at a depth's level 2. This command will go through the entire tree instead of just process both first depth's level.

Comment: `ls -d */*/` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the listing if you add the `grep` command like this example:

```
find $mydir -name "BILL_*.pdf" | grep "$mydir/BILL"
```

Good luck...

Answer (score 0):

Refer [find manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds2/find.htm)

```
-depth  Always evaluates to the value True. Causes the descent of the  
directory hierarchy to be done so that all entries in a directory are 
affected before the directory itself is affected. It can be useful    
when the find command is used with the cpio command to transfer files 
that are contained in directories without write permission.
```

So it does not accept an argument.

Comment: Yes, but this option cannot help the find command to process only a given number of depth's level.